# Chef-Solo user resource not accessing via SSH

Tags: ssh, vagrant, chef-solo

I'm using Chef-Solo and after creating a new user, I can't connect via SSH.

My resource:

```
user 'myuser' do
    supports :manage_home => true
    gid "root"
    home '/home/myuser'
    system true
    shell '/bin/bash'
    password 'mypassword'
end
```

Command line:

```
$ ssh myuser@myhost
myuser@myhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

But `$ ssh vagrant@myhost` with password `vagrant` is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the password shadow hash for the 'password' attribute. Not the plain password.

Have a look at the [official documentation](http://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html).